# Replace current process with invocation of subprocess?

Tags: python, process, replace

In python, is there a way to invoke a new process in, hand it the same context, such as standard IO streams, close the current process, and give control to the invoked process? This would effectively 'replace' the process.

I have a program whose behavior I want to repeat. However, it uses a third-party library, and it seems that the only way that I can truly kill threads invoked by that library is to exit() my python process.

Plus, it seems like it could help manage memory.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You may be interested in [`os.execv()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=execv#os.execv) and friends:

> These functions all execute a new program, replacing the current
>   process; they do not return. On Unix, the new executable is loaded
>   into the current process, and will have the same process id as the
>   caller. Errors will be reported as OSError exceptions.

Comment: Note that a call would look somewhat like `os.execvp('python.exe', ['python.exe', 'arg1', 'arg2'])`. Note the somewhat counter-intuitive `'python.exe'` appearing twice. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18552137/1143274) for more details.

Comment: Is there an equivalent `subprocess` call we're supposed to use?

Comment: @tback - Not really - it's much more of a platform-specific thing, and generally considered a lot more niche than spawning a *separate* subprocess.