# Killing a Python script from another script spawned from it

Tags: python, linux, process

I have two Python scripts on a Linux system. Let's call them service and killer. Service is run as a systemd service and killer as a script. Killer exists to perform certain tasks that can't be executed while service is running due to limited hardware resources and the will to keep the code simple.

What I need is to be able to start killer from service and then have killer kill service without dying itself (as a child process). How can I do that?

These are what I have tried so far (without success):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("killer.py")

import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["killer.py"])

import sh
killer = sh.command("killer.py")
killer()
```

Comment: Why do you need the kill-the-parent approach? Can't your service just spawn the child subprocess and exit?

Comment: Use `os.setsid()` in the child to disconnect from the parent.  Get the process id (PID) of the parent using `os.getppid()` then use `os.kill()`.  But really this is a poor design.

Comment: @Leon: I need to be sure that the parent has really died. I thought killing it from outside would be more safe.

Comment: Then you can perform all cleanup of the service process and then [replace it with the child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743567/replace-current-process-with-invocation-of-subprocess)

Comment: I'll try these suggestions a bit later today. Thanks so far!

Comment: os.setsid() did not help, and I realized that replacing the process using os.execvp() might not be a good idea since the parent process is run as a systemd service.

Comment: I ended up solving this by extending another systemd service that was already in the system. That service will now take care of starting killer when told so by service via D-Bus. That way, killer is no longer run as a child of service.