# How to change directory from python script

Tags: python, bash

This code opens a new bash in need directory.

```py
os.chdir(path)
os.system("bash")
```

I want an exit from python script and stay in the bash console. But need to go to the directory.

How does it?
Help me, please.

Comment: Why not just define the path you want to do work in in either python or bash?

Comment: The path is selected in the console application

Comment: Are you looking for `os.execv`? See [Replace current process with invocation of subprocess?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6743567/4518341)

Comment: bash is not a console.

Comment: You cannot change the environment of a process (including its current working directory) from a child process. That's why `cd` is a shell built-in, not an external command.

Comment: @chepner Thank you! I understand now. I will rewrite my app on bash.)

Comment: A workaround: `exec ./script.py`